# Mysql procedure to insert data from file

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an application that save data into a table , say **my_table**.

```
my_table
id | name | salary
```

this is a data entry application and not having a centralized database.Once all data entries complete, I have to merge the databases. My plan is to export insert statements from say **DB2** and append it to **DB1**. So i wrote a procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertToTable
DECLARE max_id INT DEFAULT 1
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(id) INTO max_id FROM my_table

    INSERT INTO table(id,name,salary) VALUES(max_id+1,'tom',1000);
    INSERT INTO table(id,name,salary) VALUES(max_id+1,'john',1500);
    ....//a lot of statements 

END
```

here i just increment id of DB2 by the max(id) of DB1 to avoid conflict.It works fine.

But some databases have large number of records.I could get these insert statements with 'max_id' variable in position.Then can I execute these 'insert' statements from file inside that procedure. Or is there any better solution..

Answer (score 1):

Make "Id" column auto incremental by adding sequence.
Then create a trigger that increment upon insert.

Comment: I think u misunderstood. My problem is that i have more than one database with same schema or same table. Table in each database starts with primary key say '1'. Then i need to append one database with next and so on, to get a merged single database.

Comment: Sorry for not getting your problem, can u please elaborate or explain with an example what actually you want.

Comment: Actually my insert statements reside in a file, not like in the procedure given in question. Can I execute these statements (from file) inside my procedure instead of writing these insert statements inside my procedure (since i have to execute a large number of ststements).

Comment: Instead of having INSERT statements you can have data in the excel file and for accessing the data from excel file you can refer to solution 4050790.

Comment: i selected procedure since i need to change **id** of the new insert statements using variable 'max_id', since we are appending to an existing database table.

Comment: ok.. i think u are correct.let me check on 'trigger' for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think i need this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_test BEFORE INSERT ON table my_table
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      SET @max_id = select max(id) from my_table;
        IF NEW.id >= @max_id THEN 
            NEW.id = @max_id + 1;
        END IF;
END;
```

Thanks for your suggestion.